# C# marker structures performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance

In F#, we have several very nice solutions for design-time type safety: type aliases and single-case struct union (and no implicit conversions to start with!):

```
// type aliases are erased at compile time
type Offset = int64<offset>

// no allocations
[<Struct>]
type Offset = Offset of int64
```

*What would be an alternative for C#?*

I have never seen a practical usage of marker structures (containing a single element), but it looks like if we add *explicit* type conversions then we could get design-time behavior very similar to type aliases in F#. That is - IDE will complain about type mismatches and one will have to explicitly cast values.

Below is some POC code:

```
public struct Offset {
    private readonly long _value;
    private Offset(long value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static explicit operator Offset(long value) {
        return new Offset(value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static explicit operator long(Offset offset) {
        return offset._value;
    }
}

public interface IIndex<T> {
    Offset OffsetOf(T value);
    T AtOffset(Offset offset);
}

public class SmapleUsage
{
    public void Test(IIndex<long> idx)
    {
        // without explicit cast we have nice red squiggles
        var valueAt = idx.AtOffset((Offset)123);
        long offset = (long)idx.OffsetOf(42L);
    }
}
```

So, the IDE thing is nice! But I was going to ask *what are performance implications and other downsides*, and to avoid "just measure it" comments have just measured it and stopped writing this question initially... But the results came out counter-intuitive:

```
[Test]
public void OffsetTests() {
    var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 1024).ToArray();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    for (int rounds = 0; rounds < 10; rounds++) {
        sw.Restart();
        long sum = 0;
        for (int rp = 0; rp < 1000000; rp++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                sum += GetAtIndex(array, i);
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        if (sum < 0) throw new Exception(); // use sum after loop
        Console.WriteLine($"Index: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

        sw.Restart();
        sum = 0;
        for (int rp = 0; rp < 1000000; rp++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                sum += GetAtOffset(array, (Offset)i);
            }
        }
        if (sum < 0) throw new Exception(); // use sum after loop
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Offset: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

        sw.Restart();
        sum = 0;
        for (int rp = 0; rp < 1000000; rp++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                sum += array[i];
            }
        }
        if (sum < 0) throw new Exception(); // use sum after loop
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Direct: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private int GetAtIndex(int[] array, long index) {
    return array[index];
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private int GetAtOffset(int[] array, Offset offset) {
    return array[(long)offset];
}
```

Surprisingly, on i7@2.2Hz x64/Release the case with `Offset` is visibly faster on every test round - typical values are:

```
Int64: 1046
Offset: 932
Direct: 730
```

I would expect equal or slower result compared to just using `int64`. So *what is going one here?* Could you reproduce the same difference or spot some deficiency, e.g. if I measure different things?

Comment: have you looked at the generated IL?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, yes, obviously for `Offset` it calls the op_explicit methods and has more lines - so from IL perspective it does more job. But other than that the code is the same. Likely some JIT peculiarities if the result is reproducible.

Comment: The results are a bit different for "true" 64-bit (Prefer 32-bit off), but in general I would not bother for performance - a `struct` that is wrapping a single primitive member should really be the same as using the member.

Comment: @IvanStoev I am definitely running in x64 mode. Do you mean compiling it as x64, not as AnyCPU?

Comment: I meant to go to Project Properties -> Build tab and uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox, which is checked by default.

Comment: @IvanStoev my test runner is x64 and test assembly is compiled as x64 (not AnyCPU). Assemly with `Offset` definition is AnyCPU. How `Prefer 32-bit` alone could affect anything!?

Comment: Well, that wasn't clear from your post. All I meant was that I've tried your test in Release build, AnyCPU, and with `Prefer 32-bit` it showed results similar to yours, while with that box unchecked the Index test is a bit faster than Offset, but the difference is negligible - approx. 10ms

Comment: @IvanStoev I should have made the `i7@2.2Hz x64/Release` part bold :) Any ideas why the difference?

Comment: Ok, I see it :) Tried that as well, and got the same results as AnyCPU/prefer 32-bit=off. i.e. Int64 is a bit faster. But anyway, I have no idea why, and the question is, does it really matter? The performance seems to be just fine, so no worry, move on.

Comment: It is always interesting when the result are counter intuitive. I am moving on already and using the structure.

Comment: Agreed :) Btw, if you change the two `GetAtXXX` methods to be `static`, you'll get different results (more intuitive :) So yes, interesting thing, but too many thing involved in order to make conclusions. Most probably some difference in JIT-ters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Once you replace `for (int i = 0;` with `for (long i = 0;` in the Int64 test, the performance will be identical to the Direct test.

While using `int` it generates such x86-64 instructions:

```
inc         ecx  
cmp         ecx,0F4240h
```

While using `long` it generates such x86-64 instructions:

```
inc         rcx  
cmp         rcx,0F4240h
```

So the only difference in using 32-bit register `ecx` or its 64-bit version `rcx`, where later is faster due to a CPU design.

**2.** Use `long` for iterator in Offset test, and you'll see similar performance.

**3.** Because the code is optimized in release mode, there is almost no difference between using `Int64` or `Offset`, however at some point the instructions are little bit re-arranged.

While using Offset (one instruction less):

```
movsxd      rdx,eax  
movsxd      r8,r14d  
cmp         rdx,r8  
jae         <address>
```

While using Int64 (one instruction more):

```
movsxd      rdx,r14d  
movsxd      r8,eax  
cmp         r8,rdx  
jae         <address>  
movsxd      rdx,eax
```

**4.** The direct test is the fastest, because it does not do array boundary checks with instructions shown above at #3. This optimization happens when you write a loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.Length; i++) { ... array[i] ... }
```

Normally, if your index is outside of the bounds of the array it throws the `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but in this case compiler knows that it cannot happen, so it omits the check.

Then, even having extra instruction in other tests, they have similar performance due to CPU branch predictor, which starts running instructions in advance if needed, and discards the results if condition fails.

Comment: This is so awesome! Thanks! :)